# Параллельное считывайте файла

Tags: java, файлы, io, randomaccessfile

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по такому вопросу. Есть очень большой файл на несколько десятков тысяч строк. Программа должна считывать строку и помещать её в массив String[]. Как можно параллельно считать файл в два потока. Например, первый потоr обрабатывает количество строк от начала и до середины, а второй с середины и до конца?

Answer (score 1):

Читать файл в несколько потоков не имеет смысла - это приведет к увеличению времени чтения. Вам нужно вычитать часть данных (если есть ресурсы весь файл) в буффер. И уже обработку буффера разделить на несколько потоков. В зависимости от логики обработки можно использовать [`newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) или [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html).